# Scrape Google Search Result Description Using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-search

I want to Scrape Google Search Result Description Using BeautifulSoup but I am not able to scrape the tag which is containing the description.

Ancestor:

```
html
body#gsr.srp.vasq.wf-b
div#main
div#cnt.big
div.mw
div#rcnt
div.col
div#center_col
div#res.med
div#search
div
div#rso
div.g
div.rc
div.IsZvec
div
span.aCOpRe
```

Children

```
em
```

Python Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import bs4.builder._lxml
import re

search = input("Enter the search term:")
param = {"q": search}

r = requests.get("https://google.com/search?q=", params = param)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

title = soup.findAll("div",class_ = "BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd")

for t in title:
    print(t.get_text())

description = soup.findAll("span", class_ = "aCOpRe")

for d in description:
    print(d.get_text())

print("\n")
link = soup.findAll("a")

for link in  soup.find_all("a",href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print(re.split(":(?=http)",link["href"].replace("/url?q=","")))
```

[Image Link displaying the tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMQk1.jpg)

Comment: Does the page include javascript which actually retrieves the results? If so you won’t be able to ‘scrap’ anything that is retrieved by the javascript - you’ll have to use a browser simulation like Selenium.

Comment: Is there any way to access the em element which is under the span.aCOpRe

Answer (score 1):

The proper CSS selector for snippets (descriptions) of Google Search results is `.aCOpRe span:not(.f)`.

Here's [a full example in online IDE](https://repl.it/@serpapi/GoogleSearchResultsSnippets).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

param = {"q": "coffee"}
headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15"
}

r = requests.get("https://google.com/search", params=param, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")
soup.prettify()

title = soup.select(".DKV0Md span")

for t in title:
    print(f"Title: {t.get_text()}\n")

snippets = soup.select(".aCOpRe span:not(.f)")

for d in snippets:
    print(f"Snippet: {d.get_text()}\n")

link = soup.findAll("a")

for link in soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile("(?<=/url\?q=)(htt.*://.*)")):
    print(re.split(":(?=http)", link["href"].replace("/url?q=", "")))
```

Output

```
Title: Coffee - Wikipedia

Title: Coffee: Benefits, nutrition, and risks - Medical News Today

...

Snippet: Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species. When coffee berries turn from green to bright red in color – indicating ripeness – they are picked, processed, and dried.

Snippet: When people think of coffee, they usually think of its ability to provide an energy boost. ... This article looks at the health benefits of drinking coffee, the evidence ...

...
```

Alternatively, you can extract data from Google Search via [SerpApi](https://serpapi.com/search-api).

`curl` example

```sh
curl -s 'https://serpapi.com/search?q=coffee&location=Sweden&google_domain=google.se&gl=se&hl=sv&num=100'
```

Python example

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "coffee",
    "location": "Sweden",
    "google_domain": "google.se",
    "gl": "se",
    "hl": "sv",
    "num": 100,
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY")
}

client = GoogleSearch(params)
data = client.get_dict()

print("Organic results")

for result in data['organic_results']:
    print(f"""
Title: {result['title']}
Link: {result['link']}
Position: {result['position']}
Snippet: {result['snippet']}
""")
```

Output

```
Organic results

Title: Coffee - Wikipedia
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee
Position: 1
Snippet: Coffee is a brewed drink prepared from roasted coffee beans, the seeds of berries from certain Coffea species. When coffee berries turn from green to bright red ...


Title: Drop Coffee
Link: https://www.dropcoffee.com/
Position: 2
Snippet: Drop Coffee is an award winning roastery in Stockholm, representing Sweden four times in the World Coffee Roasting Championship, placing second, third and ...

...
```

**Disclaimer**: I work at SerpApi.

Comment: I would add time interval for sleep before reading page to soup and prettify since not all times is right response.

Comment: @mindaugas-vaitkus, it's interesting. Do you have an example of code that leads to race condition?

Comment: I use sometimes selenium it has implicitwait method instead of using time sleep as explicit method. It waits till page fully loads.

Comment: With Selenium or other browser automation - yes, `wait` or `sleep` is needed. But `requests` are synchronous and no wait is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `CSS` selector and then just pull the text out.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=scrap").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser").select(".s3v9rd.AP7Wnd")

for item in soup:
    print(item.getText(strip=True))
```

Sample output for `scrap`:

> discard or remove from service (a redundant, old, or inoperative
> vehicle, vessel, or machine), especially so as to convert it to scrap
> metal.

Comment: It is working but it is selecting all the texts present in the google search result page. I want to scrap the content which is given with the link.

Comment: <div><span class="aCOpRe"><span>10<em>Lionel Messi</em> The G.O.A.T plays for barcelona and argentina</span></span></div>                                                        I want to get the text: 10 Lionel Messi The G.O.A.T plays for barcelona and argentina

Comment: It's *scrape* **not** *scrap*.

Comment: When I am trying to scrape not scrap : soup.findAll("span", class_="aCOpRe"), it is returning None.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
the code gets all the title and links and breadcrumbs and descriptions of the google search results(no featured section, people who ask)which you can see when you search for something

```
 query = "Your search term"
    driver_location = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--lang=en,en_US')
    # options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    # options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
  options.add_argument('Accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,i

mage/webp')
# options.add_argument('Accept-Encoding= gzip')
# options.add_argument('Accept-Language= en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8')
# options.add_argument('Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1')
# options.add_argument('image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3')
# options.add_argument('user-agent=' + ua['google chrome'])
# options.add_argument('proxy-server=' + "115.42.65.14:8080")
# options.add_argument('Referer=' + "https://www.google.com/")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_location,chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q={}&oq={}&hl=en&num=50".format(urllib.parse.quote(query),urllib.parse.quote(query)))
p = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tF2Cxc")
titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yuRUbf")
descriptions = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("IsZvec")
time.sleep(10)

link_list = []
description_list = []
featured = False
featured_links = 0
title_list = []
featured_max = 0
featured_num = 0

for index in range(len(p)):
    p_items = p[index].get_attribute("innerHTML")
    print(p_items)
    items_soup = BeautifulSoup(p_items,"html.parser")
    if(featured==False):
        if((len(items_soup.text.split("\n")) != 2)):
            print(items_soup.text.split("\n"))
            if ((items_soup.select(".IsZvec") != None) and 
                   (items_soup.select(".IsZvec")[0].text != "") and (items_soup.select(".IsZvec") != "")):
                a = items_soup.select("a",recursive=False)[0]["href"]
                print(a)
                link_list.append(a)
    title_list.append(titles[index].text)
    description_list.append(descriptions[index].text)
description_list_new = []
title_list_new = []
for index in range(len(description_list)):
    if (description_list[index] == ""):
        pass
    elif (re.findall(r'<\w{1,}\s\w{1,}>',description_list[index]) != []):
        pass
    else:
        description_list_new.append(description_list[index])
        title_list_new.append(title_list[index])
description_list = description_list_new
title_list = title_list_new

for title in range(len(title_list)):
    print(title_list[title])
    print(description_list[title])
    print("=======================")
print(link_list)
print(len(title_list))
print(len(link_list))
```

Comment: note its in comments because stack overflows code block was bugging.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on playwright:

```
import json
import asyncio
import playwright
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright


async def search(query: str, headless: bool = True):
    """
    This function searches Google for the given query and returns the organic search results in JSON format.
    :param query: The search query
    :return: JSON data containing the organic search results
    """

    # Launch the browser and create a new page
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=headless)
        context = await browser.new_context(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4454.0 Safari/537.36',
                                      permissions=['geolocation', 'notifications'])
        try:
            page = await context.new_page()

            # Navigate to Google search page
            await page.goto('https://www.google.com')

            # Get Iframe callout
            # check if iframe is visile if not continue

            # wait page is loaded
            await page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')

            # button accept cookies
            buttonAcceptAll = await page.query_selector('button#L2AGLb')

            if buttonAcceptAll is not None:
                buttonAcceptAll.click()
            else:
                pass

            iframe = await page.query_selector("iframe[name='callout']")

            if iframe is not None:
                await page.frame_locator("iframe[name='callout']").get_by_role(
                    'button').click()
            else:
                pass

            await page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Search").click()
            await page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Search").fill(query)
            await page.get_by_role("combobox", name="Search").press("Enter")

            # Wait for search results to load
            await page.wait_for_selector('div#search')

            # Extract the search results
            results = await page.query_selector_all('.g')

            # Create a list to store the search results
            search_results = []

            # Loop through each search result and extract the required information
            for index, result in enumerate(results):
                position = index + 1

                title = ''
                link = ''
                displayed_link = ''
                favicon = ''
                description = ''
                snippet = ''
                source = ''

                if result is not None:
                    title_element = await result.query_selector('h3')
                    if title_element is not None:
                        title = await title_element.inner_text()
                    link_element = await result.query_selector('a')
                    if link_element is not None:
                        link = await link_element.get_attribute('href')
                    displayed_link_element = await result.query_selector(
                        ".TbwUpd")
                    if displayed_link_element is not None:
                        displayed_link = await displayed_link_element.inner_text()
                    favicon_element = await result.query_selector(
                        '.eqA2re.NjwKYd img')
                    if favicon_element is not None:
                        favicon = await favicon_element.get_attribute('src')
                    description_element = await result.query_selector(
                        '.MUxGbd.yXK7lf.MUxGbd.yDYNvb.lyLwlc')
                    if description_element is not None:
                        description = await description_element.inner_text()
                    snippet_element = await result.query_selector(
                        '.VwiC3b.yXK7lf.MUxGbd.yDYNvb.lyLwlc span:last-child')
                    if snippet_element is not None:
                        snippet = await snippet_element.inner_text()
                    source_element = await result.query_selector(
                        '.TbwUpd.NJjxre.iUh30.apx8Vc.ojE3Fb span.VuuXrf')
                    if source_element is not None:
                        source = await source_element.inner_text()

                # Create a dictionary for each search result
                result_dict = {
                    "position": position,
                    "title": title,
                    "link": link,
                    "displayed_link": displayed_link,
                    "favicon": favicon,
                    "description": description,
                    "snippet": snippet,
                    "source": source
                }

                # Append the result dictionary to the search_results list
                search_results.append(result_dict)

            # Create a dictionary to store the final JSON result
            json_result = {
                "organic_results": search_results
            }

            json_data =  json_result

            return json_data
        except Exception as e:
            error = {
                "error": str(e)
            }
            return error
        finally:
            # Close the browser
            await context.close()
            await browser.close()
```

The complete project is available there:    https://github.com/raphaelmansuy/GoogleSearch